# How to fetch content of dynamic link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown menu in my 1stpage.php. When a user select an option from that dropdown menu, content is fetch from 2ndpage.php into a div named "container". The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("select.opt").change(function(){
    $.post("2ndpage.php", function(data){
        $("#container").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

html layout:

```
<div>
<select class="opt">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="container></div>
```

However, content from the 2ndpage.php has clickable link like

```
This is content from 2ndpage.php
If you click <a href="3rdpage.php">Here</a>
You will get content from 3rdpage.php
```

I want that, if a user click on the link (Here), content from the 3rdpage.php will be fetched and will show on the "container" div, instead redirected the whole 1stpage.php to 3rdpage.php.

How to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your first page, you can add a delegated event handler which will be listening for the `<a href="3rdpage.php">Here</a>` from second page. Inside this event handler, you should prevent the default action of hyperlink using `event.preventDefault()` and get the content of `3rdpage.php` and append it manually using `$.post()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("select.opt").change(function(){
     $.post("2ndpage.php", function(data){
       $("#container").html(data);
     });
  });
  $(document).on("click",'a[href="3rdpage.php"]',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = this.href // 3rdpage.php
    $.post(target, function(data){
       $("#container").html(data);
     });
  });
});
```

---

Side note: Not sure why are you **POST**ing to the server for **GET**ting data. You should be using `$.get()`, If the server listens to GET requests, you can use the shortcut [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to directly insert the data into matching element, for eg:

`$("#container" ).load( "3rdpage.php")`

Comment: What if there will be "?id=" in each hyperlink, like: This is content from 2ndpage.php
If you click <a href="3rdpage.php?id=4">Here</a>
You will get 4th para from 3rdpage.php. If you click <a href="3rdpage.php?id=5">Here</a>
You will get 5th para from 3rdpage.php. Obviously this request will be $.get whereas the first request (calling 2ndpage.php) will be $.Post

Comment: @stockBoi You can strip the data by string manipulation or using regex, for ef, `var id = this.href.split("?id=")[1]` and then use it in load like `$("#container" ).load("3rdpage.php p#"+id)`

Comment: Depends on which method you're using (`.load()`,`$.get()`,`$.post()`). I suggest `load()` because it can strip a particular element from the fetched document, which you've to do manually if you're using other methods. If you're unable to figure it out maybe post a new question with your current setup...

Comment: But how can I select a with dynamic href on click event? I meant what will be selector?

Comment: @stockBoi Give it a common class, and your selector will be `a.commonClassName`, or a name, a data attribute etc and use the attribute selector like `a[name="linkToThirdPage"]` ...

Answer (score 0):

Use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) Method for loading dynamically usin JQuery into DIV.

```
$( "#container" ).load( "3rdpage.php")
```

OR -
It Seems, You should use Master page and Child page Concept for this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind a click event and prevent the default behaviour (which is to open the link on click):

```
$('a[href="3rdpage.php"]').on({
  click: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // This will prevent your link from opening
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
      // Do whatever you want with your data
    });
  }
});
```